# Is Migration from Struts to Spring wholesale change?

Tags: spring, struts-1

I have a Struts 1 application and I am exploring different options for upgrading the system. One option is Spring MVC or Spring Boot.  If I were to choose either framework to migrate the application to, can I do so transitionally (piece by piece) or would it be a complete wholesale change or complete rewrite. Don't know if I'm making myself understood.

Comment: You can run multiple frameworks in an app. As to whether or not you *should*, that's a different discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring 3.0, had explicit support for integrating struts 1.  This was two major versions of spring and 9 years ago.  There is documentation here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/web-integration.html#struts

Integration consisted in either using the `ContextLoaderPlugin` to allow spring to manage all your action classes, or to make your action classes aware of the spring context. A fair amount of struts specific code was available to do things like map struts action handlers to action beans in the spring context.

You could probably reproduce a lot of this in spring 5, but you'd have to do a lot of heavy lifting on your own. There are probably very few struts/spring 5 users out there to help you.

You could also go with spring 3.0 to make the integration easier, allowing you to do the migration in steps, but then you are in a different bad place. You have an old version of spring that fewer people use, and none of the goodness that 9 years of releases have wrought.

If you want to migrate your struts 1 app to spring, you are probably going to have to do it all at once.  Redo your action classes as springmvc controllers and then rewrite your views (templates).  spring mvc is pretty view agnostic and there are many good choices.

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Thank you for your insight it is appreciated

Comment: I also doubt struts 1 will actually run on java 8 (which is a requirement for Spring 5). However porting the struts 1 code to a newer Spring versions shouldn't be that hard (we actually did it once in a 4.x scenario) that way you have a gradual migration path.

Comment: @M.Deinum struts does runs on Java 8

Comment: Struts runs in JDK17

Answer (score 0):

To switch over to Spring MVC or Spring Boot is a rewrite since they're different UI technologies.

If you want to retain Struts as your UI technology but avail yourself of Spring dependency injection you can see the solution I posted in [Struts 1 to Spring Migration - Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57186714/struts-1-to-spring-migration-strategy/76896848#76896848)